# Xamarin for a small development team with .Net experience?

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Xamarin is great in theory but would it be a good fit for a small team with .Net experience that is looking to build a consumer facing (not LOB) app for Android, iOS & Windows Mobile.  This is not a build and forget scenario.  The app would be under continuous development, and deployment via the three app stores.

Xamarin seems better suited for a large enterprise with many resources and a pool of .Net developers.  I am looking for feedback from those who have actually invested time and money going the Xamarin route.

Although I feel a small .Net team could be more productive in the short term with Xamarin, I have the following reservations that have not vanished through experimenting with Xamarin or through reading countless docs, articles and comments.

- Hitting hard roadblocks after investing months on development and finding it very difficult to get the help needed to work through the issues.  i.e small online community and expensive training and support options.
- Xamarin being unable to do something that can be done natively.
- Investing in Xamarin at the cost of not actually learning objective C (Java not a real concern).

Comment: Tool recommendations, and questions that invite discussion, are generally off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the many of opinionated questions about Xamarin vs full native. If you have no obj-c/java developers and only .net developers, then go xamarin. If you want a single code base and not have each app in a different language, go xamarin. They are pretty darn good at having support the day that iOS is released.

Search on here for all of the other questions about it to see peoples' pros and cons lists.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through Xamarin route and I do development on C# for many years. I do Java and learned Objective-C to develop on iOS. Right now I do it alone or at most with some friends , so it is like the small team scenario you described.

I would not go on any other route for some reasons:

- Needing to deploy on more than one platform and do each one on a different language is something I dislike
- Xamarin exposes all the native APIs on each platform, so I am at no loss
- I can access third party native libraries on each platform with ease
- The non-native issue is not a issue for me for the byte-codes are native on iOS and there is a small Runtime on Android, but on both cases the performance is not at loss
- I have done some basic and intermediary stuff using Xamarin and there were no lack of support from the community, documentation or from Xamarin
- I am not getting to be an expert on Objective-C, as I don't develop using it, but I am learning the native APIs and their use the same way. You will use all the same Objects, methods (protocols and delegates) you would with Objective-C but now you have a different syntax (one which I love by the way)